# Python Interactive axis range - set axis limits with silders in pylab/numpy

Tags: python, numpy, python-2.7, matplotlib

I'm using Python 2.7 .
Is there a way to set *xlim* and *ylim* using sliders?

```
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np
x=np.arange(0,10,0.01)
y=pl.sin(x)*0.1*x
pl.plot(x,y)
pl.xlim(3,9)
pl.ylim(-1,1)
pl.show()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, there is a way to change plot limits, just not with xlim,ylim but with redefinition of axis.

Scenario:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.axis([0,200,0,500])
```

add1) axis are defined as [x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max]

add2) just to be sure:

```
 print ax.axis()
```

> (0.0, 200.0, 0.0, 500.0)

**Then, you can do in slider update function:**

```
def update(val):
        ax.axis([0,200,0,1000])
```

so,

```
print ax.axis()
```

> (0.0, 200.0, 0.0, 1000.0)